# AWS EMR managed auto scaling is automatically scaling down to 0 task nodes and again adding task nodes to and fro while the spark job is running

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-auto-scaling, apache-hudi

**Environment**: AWS EMR cluster with managed autosclaing turned on and running hudi job

**Issue**: I enabled auto scaling with minimum 2 nodes and maximum 8 task nodes capacity and maximum 2 core nodes, with 2 on demand capacity.

I ran a spark job, it autoscaled it to 4 task nodes once job ran and immediately started to scale down and resized it to 2 task nodes. 2 task nodes were getting decommissioned. Then it scaled down to 0 task nodes and again started adding 2 nodes from 0. During whole process it was switching task nodes from 0 to 2-4 nodes and back to 0 again and again even job was still running. This behavior of scaling down and again scaling up in-between is strange.

Anyone have any idea if I am missing anything? TIA

**Note**: I checked resource manager, nodes were being used at full capacity, cores were being used to their max.

Comment: Hi, would you be able to share your cluster ID? I am on the EMR team and could share this post with somebody who is responsible for this feature.

Comment: You can create a support ticket to ask AWS about the problem https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home